# Copy complete text line followed by specific pattern

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, sed

I need to copy a whole line of text which comes after a pattern using linux command line.

I have a text file who looks like this:

> Query= lcl|TRINITY_DN38349_c2_g130_i1 len=264 path=[13442:0-77
>   13443:78-113 13444:114-116 13445:117-137 13446:138-141 13447:142-181
>   13448:182-182 13449:183-190 13450:191-220 13451:221-237 13452:238-263]
>   [-1, 13442, 13443, 13444, 13445, 13446, 13447, 13448, 13449, 13450,
>   13451, 13452, -2]
>
> Length=612
>   Sequences producing significant alignments:
>
> ref|XP_011662878.1|  PREDICTED: deleted in malignant brain tumors... 
>   71.2    8e-11 ref|XP_011660819.1|  PREDICTED: galectin-3-binding protein-like [...  61.2    1e-08 ref|XP_011662496.1|  PREDICTED:
>   deleted in malignant brain tumors...  60.5    2e-07
>
> /ref|XP_011662878.1| PREDICTED: deleted in malignant brain tumors 1 protein-like [Strongylocentrotus  purpuratus] Length=903

I need to copy the whole lines which start with `Query= lcl|TRINITY` and `/ref|`. Problem is that I have dozens of files like this and every file has hundreds of text lines, so the numbers and text following those patters constantly changes. I wish to redirect them into a single file.

The output ideally should look like this:

> Query= lcl|TRINITY_DN38349_c2_g130_i1
>
> /ref|XP_011662878.1| PREDICTED: deleted in malignant brain tumors 1 protein-like [Strongylocentrotus  purpuratus]

Notice that the lines of interest ALWAYS start with `/ref` and `Query=`. I've read some post about using `sed` but I can't make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your desired output, `Query= lcl|TRINITY_DN38349_c2_g130_i1` is not the whole line. What do you want to output ?

Answer (score 0):

With find and sed, to get truncated lines as in your desired output sample (searching recursively from current directory) :

```
find . -type f -exec sed -n 's/^\(Query= lcl|TRINITY[^ ]*\) .*/\1/p;s/^\(\/ref.*\) .*/\1/p' '{}' \; > output
```

To save whole lines starting with `Query= lcl|TRINITY` or `/ref` :

```
find . -type f -exec sed -n '/^Query= lcl|TRINITY/p;/^\/ref.*/p' '{}' \; > output
```

Matching lines are saved to `output` file.